# How to fork a GitHub project AND keep all pull requests

Tags: github, github-issues

I am forking a GitHub project that has been abandoned.  There are about 5 important pull requests that need to be accepted (including mine!), but the project owner is AWOL.

When I use the GitHub web interface to fork the project, none of the pull requests are duplicated into my fork.

Using the GitHub web interface, how do I quickly get those pull requests into my fork?

Comment: What if you create a fork and ask all the open pull requests to submit to yours? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553156/how-do-i-merge-a-pull-request-on-someone-elses-project-in-git

Answer (score 2):

Github allows for repository transfer, requesting this transfers its issues, wiki, stars, and watchers. Bear in mind that when you're doing transfer across user accounts, Github doesn't allow for a fork to exist [in the target network.](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/)

> Transferring a repository gives the new user immediate administrative access to the repository—including its code, issues, pull requests, and releases
>
> Before you transfer a repository, keep these things in mind:
>
> The target account **must not** have a repository with the same name, or a fork in the same network.

To initiate a transfer, the owner of the repo should do this from Settings → Transfer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  As you mentioned, *transferring* the project is initiated by the current project owner.  This project owner is AWOL... no contributions and no response to emails.